# Vaadin Grid with Generated Properties and Sorting

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I have several columns in a Vaadin Grid that only contain values of items that are in a sortable Container, but they're added as Generated Properties as well due to the fact that there needs to be custom HTML title-tag to go with the value. With Generated Property and HtmlRenderer it works and renders fine, but using them makes all the columns unsortable. With a Table this could be done with a CellStyleGenerator I think, but there are several advantages with the Grid. Is there any workaround to fix this and make the columns sortable again?

Using a HtmlRenderer together with a Converter should work otherwise, but I need the object reference itself and not just the field the Converter has, as the html title-tag needs to contain some meta-information.

Answer (score 2):

I recently stumbled upon the same problem if I understood your question correctly.

---

For me, to make the generated columns sortable, I needed to override the method `getSortProperties()` when providing the `ValuGenerator<T>` to the `GeneratedPropertyContainer`:

```
GeneratedPropertyContainer container = new GeneratedPropertyContainer(originalContainer);
container.addGeneratedProperty("property-id", new PropertyValueGenerator<T>() {

  [...]

  @Override
  public SortOrder[] getSortProperties(SortOrder order) {
    return new SortOrder[] {order};
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried to achieve the same and added the suggested getSortProperties method. The sort indicators appear in the column header when clicking it, but the Grid's sorting does not change. Is this problem familiar to you? Can you provide the full code of the anonymous PropertyValueGenerator class?